# Android studio: Unable to detect adb version, exit value 0xc0000135

Tags: java, windows, adb, redmi-device

When I connect my mobile with PC, android studio says Unable to detect adb version, exit value 0xc0000135. what to do?

Comment: Update: I forgot to mention that I'm using Redmi 5A HD

Comment: I have different value though : Unable to detect adb version, exit value: 0xc0000409

Answer (score 1):

```
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145
    After that run as administrator that downloaded file> 
        then Go to android studio> 
        select device>
        click on  Troubleshoot device connection>
        connection assistant>
        scroll click next>
        Click on Restart ADB server button>
        connect device > enable debugging> it works fine after that
```

Comment: Bro, where ever in the world u are rn BIG hugs to u man. I have been stuck at this forever and nothing worked for me except this. Hv a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Windows `adb` binaries included with the latest Google official `platform-tools` package require `Universal C Runtime v1.1.0` libraries. The easiest way to get them is to install [Visual C++ Redistributable Package for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. My solution was to install 2019 visual studio community edition, all the missing packages comes with it. 
Link: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/

Comment: Please, try to write nice and well and avoid grammatical errors.

Comment: The question is about Android Studio, not Visual Studio.