# android studio's window flickering on windows 8.1 pro

Tags: windows, android-studio

I installed android studio version 3.5.2.After opening any project android studio screen is flickering continuously.In event log message is coming like this:

Unable to detect adb version, exit value: 0xc0000135. ADB depends on the Windows Universal C Runtime, which is usually installed by default via Windows Update. You may need to manually fetch and install the runtime package here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

When I go to the website, Update is no longer is available.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to force Windows Update to search for updates? if it's available in somewhere trustable it might find.

Comment: Yes, I have tried for windows update. But it keep saying "searching for update" with a popup.But no update is showing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59956887/1778421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working link to the official Microsoft [Universal C Runtime](https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/5/D/C5D68AA1-F62E-422A-9084-4AD85CEB8D4D/WindowsUCRT.zip) redistributable package.

But I haven't tried it myself because I'm using Linux.

Comment: That works. I already downloaded it. But it doesn't get installed previously.