# Unable to detect adb version, exit value: 0xc0000135

Tags: java, android, android-studio

1. android studio latest vision i have use.
2. HEXM install already in my pc.
3. android virtual device not create its show unknown problem.
4. ok so i use genymoiton emulator but android studio not dected it.

Unable to detect adb version, exit value: 0xc0000135. ADB depends on the Windows Universal C Runtime, which is usually installed by default via Windows Update. You may need to manually fetch and install the runtime package here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

Event log manager shows this kind of error:

[image]

Comment: I changed the title of your question to your error message. You can count on people being willing to help, so there's no need to stress that you need them to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59956887/1778421

Comment: @Abdul did you find any soluton ?

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same issue in my [windows 7 PC].
It took so much time to resolve.

It gets resolved by installing OR re-installing

```
x86: vc_redist.x86.exe
x64: vc_redist.x64.exe
ARM64: vc_redist.arm64.exe
```

You can get download links here. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

But when you try to install the above file sometimes according to your windows version and service pack. It requires some additional security updates.

In my case, I used bellow updates [for windows 7]

```
Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64
Windows6.1-KB3033929-x64
```

then after installing the above updates I installed vc_redist. And at last, you need to restart your system.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, on Windows 10, while updating Sdk tools somehow Android Studio didn't delete the older `adb.exe` from `platform-tools` folder and created a new `platform-tools-2` folder instead.

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools (only adb.exe was left)
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools-2
```

I ended up deleting the older folder and renaming the newer one to `platform-tools` and then restart Android Studio, which worked!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I did the following to resolve it:

1. Navigated to \Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
2. Renamed the \platform-tools folder to "platform-tools_archive"
3. Went here https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools and downloaded platform-tools
4. Extracted the files and moved them to \Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

Application now runs without issue (so far).

Answer (score -2):

You get this error because the system doesn't have `vc_redist` or it need to be 
reinstalled.

Install `vc_redist.x64.exe` or `vc_redist.x86.exe` from:

[The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) Reinstalling this works for helps me to get rid of this error

Comment: Please provide more information for your answers for further information.

Comment: you find this error because the system window don't have vc_redist or it could need reinstaling of vc_redist