# Android Studio : Unable to detect adb version, exit value: 0xc0000139

Tags: android, android-studio, android-developer-api

my android studio shows "Unable to detect adb version, exit value: 0xc0000139" while I generate my apk. can anyone help me to solve this problem? [here's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Gcr.jpg)

Comment: i have already installed c/c++ runtime in my pc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59915905/unable-to-detect-adb-version-exit-value-0xc0000135?rq=1